# create five bullet points programmatically in react? Users can add tasks, but I want to start with initial variable number of bullets

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to avoid hardcoding `<li>` X times, and instead want to programmatically render them.

Here is what I have right now:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

I can render them using a for loop, but is there a more elegant way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like:

Set initial state in `constructor ()`

```
this.state = {
  tasks: [
    {
      name: '',
      complete: false
    },
    {
      name: '',
      complete: false
    },
    {
      name: '',
      complete: false
    },
    {
      name: '',
      complete: false
    },
    {
      name: '',
      complete: false
    }
  ]
}
```

Then in `render ()`

```
<ul>
  { this.state.tasks.map(task => <li>{task.name}</li> }
</ul>
```

Note, you will get an error if you don't set a `key` prop. `<li key={task.uniquevaluehere}>`

Answer (score 1):

```
const list = [{name: 'tom'}, {name: 'frank'}, {name: 'Joe'}];
const renderList = this.props.list.map(function (result) {
            return (
                <li id="search-result" key={result.name} className="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{result.name}</li>
            );
        });
<ul>
{renderList}
</ul>
```

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Thanks for fixing it! I forgot it had to be an array of objects.